# Django ManifestStaticFilesStorage and urls in javascript, angular, css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, caching

I am working with Django 1.8 + AngularJS 1.4.5.

Django has an amazing feature to prevent modified files are cached: ManifestStaticFilesStorage.

Once a file is modified the collectstatic command recalculate and add to the filename the hash of the file.Then look for all the appearances of the url with that file and and replace the original filename with the hashed filename.

Eg:

```
styles.css -> styles.b8a501ed930c.css
```

And:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is compiled as:

```
<link href="/static/css/styles.b8a501ed930c.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That is very helpful, but only rename the filenames inside the {% static %} tag.

Is there any way to add this feautre to the urls inside css/js files? For example to add a hash name to the partials html templates of angularjs.

```
$routeProvider.when('/mypage', {
  templateUrl: "mypage.html", -> ("mypage.hashdigest.html")
  controller: "MyPageController"
});
```

Comment: Today we tested the ManifestStaticFilesStorage. For CSS files it replaces the filename with the hashdigest name. But for javascript files like yours, it does not.Tested with Django 1.9.9.Any news on this problem?

Comment: Finally I could do it changing the STATICFILES_STORAGE class by a custom class inheriting from ManifestFilesMixin and adding *.html and *.js to patterns

Comment: Any details available on your solution? :)